# don't work scope in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I had issues in postgresql on production. I have `organizations_controller`

```
def index
  @organizations = Organization.alphabetically
end
```

and in my model `organization.rb`

```
scope :alphabetically, -> { order("title ASC") }
```

I want the organization's titles displayed in alphabetical order, in the development I use `sqlite3` and all works fine, but it does not work in production, where I use `postgres`. Any ideas? Thanks for advance!

Comment: You can pass an options hash instead of a string: `order(created_at: :asc)`

Comment: what do you mean? I tried, but on `posgres` this doesn't work

Comment: Since you've tagged this PostgreSQL, it might be a good idea to show the actual SQL your query generator is producing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

`Model.order('created_at ASC').uniq.pluck :description`

Prefer this link `https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2324` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Examine this deeper by doing:

```
Organization.alphabetically.to_sql
```

Also, take into account that ASC is the default order, so you could do the following:

```
scope :alphabetically, -> { order(:title) }
```